# awk - print on column-specific conditions, print empty fields for non-match

Tags: awk

My large file has date in $1 and 19 columns with numerical values, separated by ";". One or many columns must meet a column-specific smaller-than-condition for printout. I'd like to print them on the same line, beginning with $1 (date) – keeping the original table structure intact, ie, printing empty fields for those which do not meet their specific condition on this particular row. Only print lines with at least 1 match.

Later, I will have to exchange the printout conditions to larger-than and several between-values (<>) which is why I'm interested in a programmatic awk solution as opposed to  manipulation of data in a time-consuming spreadsheet application.
My OS is MacOS.

Excerpt from input; changed ";" to "," because the system didn't let me use ";" and added spaces to the delimiter for readability):

```
1503_12_26  ,  100.09  ,  33.54  ,  75.72  ,  9.17  ,  96.01  ,  29.46  ,  71.64  ,  5.09  ,  98.96  ,  32.41  ,  74.59  ,  8.04  ,  28.33  ,  70.51  ,  95  ,  70.63  ,  28.45  ,  90.92
1503_12_27  ,  102.94  ,  31.87  ,  80.47  ,  9.4  ,  98.89  ,  27.82  ,  76.42  ,  5.35  ,  102.7  ,  31.63  ,  80.23  ,  9.16  ,  27.58  ,  76.18  ,  97.59  ,  75.12  ,  26.52  ,  93.54
1503_12_28  ,  107.76  ,  32.44  ,  87.2  ,  11.88  ,  103.26  ,  27.94  ,  82.7  ,  7.38  ,  106.64  ,  31.32  ,  86.08  ,  10.76  ,  26.82  ,  81.58  ,  100.38  ,  79.82  ,  25.06  ,  95.88
1503_12_29  ,  112.87  ,  33.57  ,  94.21  ,  14.91  ,  107.58  ,  28.28  ,  88.92  ,  9.62  ,  110.66  ,  31.36  ,  92  ,  12.7  ,  26.07  ,  86.71  ,  103.25  ,  84.59  ,  23.95  ,  97.96
1503_12_30  ,  117.99  ,  34.95  ,  101.21  ,  18.17  ,  111.69  ,  28.65  ,  94.91  ,  11.87  ,  114.68  ,  31.64  ,  97.9  ,  14.86  ,  25.34  ,  91.6  ,  106.12  ,  89.34  ,  23.08  ,  99.82
1503_12_31  ,  123.07  ,  36.51  ,  108.12  ,  21.56  ,  115.63  ,  29.07  ,  100.68  ,  14.12  ,  118.66  ,  32.1  ,  103.71  ,  17.15  ,  24.66  ,  96.27  ,  108.95  ,  94  ,  22.39  ,  101.51
1504_01_01  ,  128.08  ,  38.22  ,  114.88  ,  25.02  ,  119.42  ,  29.56  ,  106.22  ,  16.36  ,  122.58  ,  32.72  ,  109.38  ,  19.52  ,  24.06  ,  100.72  ,  111.72  ,  98.52  ,  21.86  ,  103.06
```

Desired output:

```
1503-12-26 ; ; 33.54 ; ; 9.17 ; ; ; ; 5.09 ; ; ; ; 8.04 ; ; ; ; ; ;
1503-12-27 ; ; 31.87 ; ; 9.4 ; ; ; ; 5.35 ; ; ; ; 9.16 ; ; ; ; ; ;
1503-12-28 ; ; 32.44 ; ; 11.88 ; ; ; ; 7.38 ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
1503-12-29 ; ; 33.57 ; ; 14.91 ; ; ; ; 9.62 ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
1503-12-30 ; ; 34.95 ; ; 18.17 ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
1503-12-31 ; ; ; ; 21.56 ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
```

I started out with a chain of OR || conditions for each column but couldn't think of how to empty the fields that don't match their criteria.

`awk -F";" ' $2 < 80 || $3 < 35 || $4 < 60 || $5 < 24 || $6 < 45 || $7 < 24 || $8 < 30 || $9 < 8 || $10 < 60 || $11 < 24 || $12 < 30 || $13 < 10 || $14 < 10 || $15 < 10 || $16 < 24 || $17 < 8 || $18 < 8 || $19 < 8  ' input.txt > output.txt`

It just prints all fields of a row if 1 field is a hit.

Then separate awk statements for each column in a bash-file (.sh) and appending them to output.txt. But I get separate lines for each hit, and I also won't know which column had met its condition.
So I added new fields to printout:  column header ; condition ; $value.

example:

`awk -F";" '  $3 < 35   {print $1  "\;SJMV\;<35\;" $3} ' input.txt >>output.txt`

Output:

```
1503-12-26 ; SJMV ; \<35 ; 33.54
1503-12-26 ; SJM ; \<24 ; 9.17
1503-12-26 ; JM ; \<10 ; 8.04
1503-12-26 ; SJ ; \<8 ; 5.09
```

Couldn't think of a way to get this back into the table structure, either.
I might have to do some IF, FOR, or WHILE loops within the first attempted chain of OR ||
to empty the non-matching fields. But I don't know how.

This is my first Q here. Appreciate comments re improvement, as well.

Comment: You could have more interest by having the `M` aka minimal here.   
Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Gilles-Quénot Thanks. Is it allowed to edit the Q now that it received an elegant solution?

Comment: The more you define your issue concisely, the more you will understand what's going on/wrong under the hood, and same for us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the field if its test fails.
Remember to set the output delimiter.

```
awk -F";" -v OFS=";" '
    !( $2 < 80 )  { $2="" }
    !( $3 < 35 )  { $3="" }
    !( $4 < 60 )  { $4="" }
    !( $5 < 24 )  { $5="" }
    !( $6 < 45 )  { $6="" }
    !( $7 < 24 )  { $7="" }
    !( $8 < 30 )  { $8="" }
    !( $9 < 8 )   { $9="" }
    !( $10 < 60 ) { $10="" }
    !( $11 < 24 ) { $11="" }
    !( $12 < 30 ) { $12="" }
    !( $13 < 10 ) { $13="" }
    !( $14 < 10 ) { $14="" }
    !( $15 < 10 ) { $15="" }
    !( $16 < 24 ) { $16="" }
    !( $17 < 8 )  { $17="" }
    !( $18 < 8 )  { $18="" }
    !( $19 < 8 )  { $19="" }
    { print }
' input.txt > output.txt
```

---

To exclude lines where all columns were cleared, you could check if any tests succeeded:

```
awk -F";" -v OFS=";" '
    {
        t=0

        if ( $2 < 80 )  t=1; else $2=""
        if ( $3 < 35 )  t=1; else $3=""
        if ( $4 < 60 )  t=1; else $4=""
        if ( $5 < 24 )  t=1; else $5=""
        if ( $6 < 45 )  t=1; else $6=""
        if ( $7 < 24 )  t=1; else $7=""
        if ( $8 < 30 )  t=1; else $8=""
        if ( $9 < 8 )   t=1; else $9=""
        if ( $10 < 60 ) t=1; else $10=""
        if ( $11 < 24 ) t=1; else $11=""
        if ( $12 < 30 ) t=1; else $12=""
        if ( $13 < 10 ) t=1; else $13=""
        if ( $14 < 10 ) t=1; else $14=""
        if ( $15 < 10 ) t=1; else $15=""
        if ( $16 < 24 ) t=1; else $16=""
        if ( $17 < 8 )  t=1; else $17=""
        if ( $18 < 8 )  t=1; else $18=""
        if ( $19 < 8 )  t=1; else $19=""

        if (t) print
    }
' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: If all tests are the same comparison, you could reduce repetition by declaring, say: `function try (nf,val) { if ($nf < val) t=1; else $nf="" }` and replacing `if` lines with `try(2,80)`, `try(3,35)`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution. And for the quick reply. And for the re-usable  formatting. Thanks!